# Search issue with Store

Tags: store, games, search, lumia-520

I want to download Subway Surfer and Temple Run 2 on my Nokia Lumia 520. However, when I search these games in the store, I get nothing!

I would like to know the reason behind this.

If it is some requirement that my phone is lacking then why is that I can't even search these games?
The previous behaviour of the store was like I can search the games but I can't download instead I get a notification stating that my device does not meet the hardware requirements.

Is this an issue with the store or with my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, both of those games require 1 GB of RAM<sup>(1)</sup>, and the Lumia 520 only has 512 MB. So that's the reason you're not able to find them in the Store. This should be standard behaviour - apps that aren't compatible with your phone for whatever reason don't show up in searches.

You can always search for the app at [WindowsPhone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com), or open the Store page directly on your phone by scanning a QR code (e.g. from [AAWP's app directory](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/software)). You can find the respective links for both games below:

- Temple Run 2 - [WindowsPhone.com](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=6fa921ac-1f29-42e8-9f65-e8da33fcada3), [AAWP](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/software/content/Temple-Run-2.php)
- Subway Surfers - [WindowsPhone.com](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=bedff828-2697-4cc5-8661-1206d15e3e0c), [AAWP](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/software/content/Subway-Surfers.php)

In both cases, either the WindowsPhone.com website or your phone's Store app should tell you exactly why the app is incompatible.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> - [Temple Run 2 is now available for 512 MB devices as well](http://www.wpcentral.com/temple-run-2-finally-arrives-512-mb-windows-phones)

Comment: So the store's behavior has changed?

Comment: @VivekParekh No, that has always been the way the store works.

Comment: I guess they used to notify, if my device did not meet the requirements. Like when I tried to download HERE City Lens, the store did not allow download showing that my device does not support Compass.

Comment: @VivekParekh As far as I know you you have the direct link to the app you still can see it but you can't install in this case. But search you could'nt in 8.0 version too. Just tried in my daughter's phone (520 8.0).

Comment: Oh.. I see.! :) I wish I could share that with you some how :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a Search bug. No metter what requirements your app has! It must be shown in app store and when you tap to install it, a pop-up comes and tell you that you don't have requested resources.